# SQL Server 2012 paging order by an unknown column

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a query that returns the paging of the rows from a generic table because the call that invokes this query will work on more tables and databases; the program where I'm working built the query in different parts of the code, and the only variable parameters that the database receive are **@myTable**, **@offset** and **@row**.

Initially, I tried a query for a single table like this

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY myPKColumn
OFFSET @offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @row ROWS ONLY;
```

and, with @offset = 0 and @row = 10, return me the first 10 rows ASC.

So far it works all without problem, but if I need to use this query for every table, I have problems to specify the column in the ORDER BY clause; to avoid this problem I've tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM @myTable ORDER BY (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME=@myTable and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%')
OFFSET @offset ROWS
FETCH NEXT @row ROWS ONLY;
```

this because I know from the project structure that all the tables that I could invoke have a single primary key.

The query works, but the results are a bit strange: if I pass the same parameter of the precedent query, the result is the rows from 11 to 2 DESC.

Also, changing the offset value, I figured this strange relation:

If [ @offset <= ( 100 - @row ) ]
>

> the results are the first (@row+1) DESC without the first row
>
> ( in this case all the rows between @row and @offset will never be retrieved)

Else
>

> the result are the first @row starting from the (@offset + 1)
>
> examples:
>
> ```
>    @offset = 90 and @row = 10 return rows from 13 to 2
>
>    @offset = 91 and @row = 10 return rows from 92 to 101
>
>    @offset = 101 and @row = 10 return rows from 102 to 111
> ```

I've tried some little variations like specify OBJECT_ID(...) or OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(...)) outside the second select, but without changes; also, I've tried to use the debug option, but I haven't the privileges to use it.

Any idea of what could cause this strange results?

P.S: sorry for my bad English; also it's my first post so, if I missed something I'll edit without problems

EDIT:

i found a way that logically should work, but it doesn't work:

i discovered that writing a query like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY 5 asc;
```

order my rows ascendent considering the values of the 5th column.

so i made the query:

```
select ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'myTable' and COLUMN_NAME = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME='myTable' and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%')
```

that return me the position of the column with the primary key (unluckily for me, there are a lot of table where it isn't in the 1st position); the value that return is correct (i've verified a lot of table and it works always)

So, the next step, if i run the query

```
select * from mytable ORDER BY (select ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'myTable' and COLUMN_NAME = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME='myTable' and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' )) asc;
```

works with a little problem: i can declare asc or desc, but the result is always asc. (it's not a real problem, because like said before the order is not important im my case).

Now the real problem.

The last step is the query

```
select * from mytable ORDER BY (select ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'myTable' and COLUMN_NAME = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME='myTable' and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' )) asc
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

and here nothing has changed from the problem before the edit: the result are the rows from 11 to 2 desc.

to avoid the possibility that the error could be a string interpretation of the number returned, i've add a cast to int

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
ORDER BY CAST((select ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'myTable' and COLUMN_NAME = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME='myTable' and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%' ))AS int) asc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

but nothing changed.

It seems that the new query works fine until the offset/fetch is added.

Comment: You can't have a dynamic column in an `ORDER BY`. `ORDER BY (SELECT column_name)` produces a non-deterministic order, as the rows are ordered *by the column name*, which is the same for all rows. As a result, the engine is basically allowed to return any rows in any order, so there's no relation in offsets between queries, which explains your results. (You can't have a dynamic table name in the `FROM` either, so I'm unclear how your query even works, unless you do textual replacement, or it's a table variable.) [See also](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: The order by is not important for the query, but without the  OFFSET FETCh doesn't work; so i decide to use the primary key that i'm sure it could be found in every table where i need to work.

For the query, maybe i've abused the @; what i mean is that the upper program could pass a query like

SELECT * FROM pippo ORDER BY ( ... WHERE TABLE_NAME='pippo' and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%')
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;

or a query like 

SELECT * FROM pluto ORDER BY (  ... WHERE TABLE_NAME='pluto' and CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK_%')
OFFSET 50 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;

Comment: That approach doesn't work and cannot work. Your query effectively does `ORDER BY 'myPKColumn'`, which is not the same thing as `ORDER BY myPKColumn`. The former "orders" all rows by the same string, the latter orders by actual column contents. To order by a different column at runtime, you need dynamic SQL where you *first* determine the column name, then build a new query with an `ORDER BY` on that column.

Comment: Your new attempt fails for much the same reason as your previous one - there's a specific provision for integer *constants* in an `ORDER BY` clause to indicate a column ordinal. Any other type of *expression*, including subqueries, etc, uses the values returned by that expression as the sort value. `ORDER BY 5` orders by the fifth column in the `SELECT` clause. `ORDER BY CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 5 END` orders the rows arbitrarily because every row has been assigned the value `5` for sorting purposes.

Comment: `ORDER BY <column number>` works if and only if the column number is an integer literal. You will get interesting errors if you try other variations (like `(CAST (1 AS INT))`, `@var` with `@var` set to the constant `1`, etcetera.) Think out of the box all you like, but this really can't be done without dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you want to use a dynamic column name then you'll need to use dynamic SQL. Which has a lot of drawbacks